# CIFS share mount adding slashes

Tags: linux, mount, nas, rsync

I'm facing a weird behavior with a NAS (DS218j from Synology) when mounting a shared folder.
If I use the interface to mount a CIFS share, it works well. Creating folder in the share works fine, even rsync.

But if I use the shell, mounting the same folder works fine, but once I or rsync try to create a nested folder, the result is a top level folder starting with a slash character (Windows represent it as a dot) that I cannot access, rename or delete. Files also have the same behavior.

this is my mount/rsync command :

```
mount.cifs "//192.168.1.223/SauvegardeExterne/" "/volume1/DossiersDestinations/SauvegardeExterne/"  -o iocharset=utf8,username=SavQuotidien,password=PASSWORD
rsync -avu --delete "/volume1/SauvegardeQuotidienne/Backup/" "/volume1/DossiersDestinations/SauvegardeExterne/Backup/"
```

One more weird point :
This command was fully functionnal before switch the remote NAS(Iomega ix4-200d) from RAID 10 to RAID 0

Comment: When I use the shell mount, I can't even navigate in subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at /proc/mounts resulting line with the UI mount and the shell mount differences, I ended adding this to make it work :
uid=1024,gid=100,forcegid,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,rsize=61440,nocase,nounix,noacl

btw, no clue how and why.